# Bit manipulation to convert leftmost set bits to right-side alternating bits?

Tags: python, c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to maximally optimize a low-level subroutine, but I can't figure out the fastest way to flip the bits in this specific case:

Given a binary integer `n` wherein all set bits are to the left of all clear bits (e.g. `11110000`, `110000`, `1110000`), is it possible to produce a resulting binary integer of digit length `((number of set bits in n) - 2) * 2`, with all even bits set and all odd bits clear?

Example:

```
n = 111000, answer: 10
n = 1111000, answer: 1010
n = 110, answer: 0
n = 111110000000, answer: 101010
n = 1111111111000000000, answer: 1010101010101010
```

`n` is guaranteed to have at least 2 `set bits`, and at least  (`set bits` - 1) `clear bits`

The answer must utilize only a constant number of bit manipulation and/or arithmetic operations (i.e. loopless), and can't use any type conversions (integers only, no strings).

Comment: What's the actual purpose of your subroutine and why all the restrictions? The description reads uncannily like a homework problem.

Comment: What's the allowed set of operations exactly? Anything "advanced" like popcnt, lzcnt, pext, etc? (E: it is possible without them, but it gets a bit more hairy)

Comment: @lurker I'm designing an algorithm to generate all possible permutations of size `n` binary trees with `k` number of distinct values. This is one tiny piece of it. It sounds academic I guess, but it does have real-world applications. I'm not a student.

Comment: Should `n` have at least 1 clear bit?

Comment: @sniper Good question, I added constraints to input `n`. There are some guarantees on the bit counts.

Comment: @harold Prefer `& | << >> ~ ^ + - / * %` since they're less dependent on instruction set architecture, but solutions using popcnt/lzcnt/pext/etc are welcome too (and probably fine)

Comment: "I'm trying to maximally optimize a low-level subroutine" is not demonstrated.  Post what you have tried else this is simply a request for some else to do the work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach could be to use these steps:

1. Right-justify (discard trailing zeroes)
2. Get rid of 2 set bits
3. Double the number of set bits
4. Mask out the even bits

For example, using only "basic" operations:

```
// right-justify
x = x / (x & -x)
// get rid of 2 set bits
x >>= 2
// double the number of set bits
x *= x + 2
// mask out even bits
x &= 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

That step "double the number of set bits" relies on `x` being a power of two minus one at that point. If `x` can be written as 2<sup>k</sup>-1 then `x * (x + 2)` will be (2<sup>k</sup>-1) * (2<sup>k</sup>+1) = 2<sup>2k</sup>-1 so it doubles the number of set bits.

Division is not so nice, if you had a fast `tzcnt` then you can right-justify with:

```
x >>= tzcnt(x)
```

With fast [`pdep`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pdep) (Intel Haswell and newer, works on AMD Ryzen but slowly), doubling the number of set bits can be avoided,

```
// spread out the bits to even positions
x = pdep(x, 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA)
```

And fast [`pext`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pext) could be used as an alternative right-justify,

```
// right-justify
x = pext(x, x)
```

With the common `popcnt` a more direct approach could be used, counting the number of set bits, subtracting two, then generating a pattern of that size for example by shifting `0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` right until it is short enough, or by using [`bzhi`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bzhi) to truncate it at the top.

Comment: This is great! So clear and simple. If it helps enable other solutions, I added constraints on input `n` to the original question. There are some guarantees on starting set/clear counts.

Comment: @user107870 I couldn't think of a way to use the guarantee on the number of trailing zeroes, if it was a stronger guarantee such as `tzcnt(x) == popcnt(x)` then it would make the problem much easier

Comment: @harold I wonder if, in the particular case described here, `x / (x & -x)` cannot be replaced by  `x / (-x)` ?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean I believed that for a moment (using the intuition "negation flips the bits above the rightmost set bit"), but for example -6 isn't 2, a lot of higher bits get set as well

Comment: If you want to avoid hardcoding the integer length, /3*2 does the trick. Division is slow, but good compilers can replace that division with a multiplication since 3 is a constant. (Just check godbolt to see how)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python algorithm that doesn't care how many zero bits are to the right of the first one.  It builds the answer without worrying about subtracting off 2 of the 1 bits, and at the end it shifts the result to the right by 4 bits to take this into account.

```
k = 0
n = 0b111110000

while n != 0:
    if n & 1 != 0:
        k = (k << 2) + 2
    n >>= 1

print(bin(k>>4))
```

Comment: OP asked for "no loops, please"